# Angular 2 service : correct use case

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have been learning Angular 2 for the past 2 months and I am a little confuse in the use of the services. If I am developping an app with several components and each one has a set of data to display from a web service, Can I use a single service to display the data if their are build on the same model or should i definitely create one service by component?

thanks in advance  to enlighten me on that matter

Comment: Yes, you can use one service for all of your components, provided it is injectable.

Comment: do you have any example on the topics cause I have post a question on that yesterday and no one seems to know how it works

Comment: Have you been through the "Tour of Heroes" on angular.io? It provides an example of how to use data from a single service in components. You can expand on the concept demonstrated there to do pretty much anything.

Comment: Services are pretty easy. You can start here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4 . Create a service, give it `Injectable` decorator, don't forget to declare it in `providers` array in app.module.ts, inject in your component's constructor `constructor(private iCanUseIt: MyService){}` and use it like `this.iCanUseIt.serviceFunctionOrProp`

Comment: Some info.... https://angular.io/guide/architecture#services

Comment: thank you so far for your suggestion and I think I get how services work, the matter is :"how to use it with different component". I how you don't mind give a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145874/angular-services-selecting-the-correct-url-on-click-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service in many components and don't need to create a unique service for every component.

By the [angular2 reference](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4):

> Instead of copying and pasting the same code over and over, you'll
>   create a single reusable data service and inject it into the
>   components that need it.

Also, a service is singleton, and all the instances in components are the same ( it's based on hierarchical injectors ).

Comment: 'A service is a singleton' is not strictly true. Depends on whether you are using stateful or stateless services. See my answer. Otherwise I concur with your answer as the part about not repeating yourself is a valid addition to this thread.

Answer (score 3):

Services classes (providers) are decorated with  @Injectable and can be:

- Singletons where you define them in the app-module.ts in the @ngModule  in the providers : [] array
- injected in the @Component decorator for use cases when a single service won't do.

If your service contains state then singletons would potentially cause side effects and that's when you'd place them inside [@Component](https://angular.io/api/core/Component)

The docs are misleading here.. Scroll down to Metadata Properties: to see 'providers:'

You can have stateless services for example by always returning Observables.

i.e. subscribing to called service in the component Typescript behind the HTML template.

- component class has observable properties
- html template uses observable class property in conjunction with [aysnc pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). | async